# jupyter: no kernel available

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Could someone please advise on why I am *not* getting the option to choose *python3* as a kernel ?

```
# python3 -m ipykernel install --user
Installed kernelspec python3 in /root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

# python3 -m pip install ipykernel
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.0 in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1.0 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports_abc>=0.4 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.3 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.3->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
```

From the command-line I can see indeed that the python3 kernel is installed

```
# jupyter kernelspec list
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
Available kernels:
  python3    /root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

But jupyter does not to be able to understand it:
[image]
Could someone please advise on how to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

`python3 -m IPython kernelspec install-self`    or

`python3 -m jupyter kernelspec install-self`

to reinstall the kernelspec ,
I am refering to this [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/300)

Comment: I had to `pip uninstall ipython` and then `pip install ipython` first because a package I tried to use installed the wrong version but then this worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
jupyter kernelspec install-self
```

is DEPRECATED as of 4.0.

Now you have to use

```
IPython kernel install
```

Answer (score 1):

`python3 -m jupyter kernelspec install-self`

Go to the jupyter folder which is inside Appdata/Roaming/Jupyter
Then inside the folder, you will find a kernels folder inside that there will be many kernels like python3 etc

The path should be like this,

`C:\Users\Jayasurya\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3`

Inside this find a kernel.json file
and make sure your Python executable is in the file

```
{
 "argv": [
  "c:\\python\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

The path should be inside the args list, in my code above it's in the 3rd line `"c:\\python\\python.exe"` make sure that the executable path is right

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem I installed the ipython kernel and everything worked.

```
pip install ipython
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed my kernel using this:

```
python -m IPython kernel install
```

For more subcommands:

```
    Manage Jupyter kernel specifications.
    
    Subcommands
    ===========
    Subcommands are launched as `jupyter kernelspec cmd [args]`. For information on
    using subcommand 'cmd', do: `jupyter kernelspec cmd -h`.

    - list
        List installed kernel specifications.

    - install
        Install a kernel specification directory.

    - uninstall
        Alias for remove.

    - remove
        Remove one or more Jupyter kernelspecs by name.

    - install-self
        [DEPRECATED] Install the IPython kernel spec directory for this Python.

    - provisioners
        List available provisioners for use in kernel specifications.
```